# reference the a split form? The audit table isn't picking it up VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to create audit trail form in MS Access. The audit table isn't picking it up. I have a doubt on referencing the form in the VBA sctript. Can anyone help on, How to reference the a split form? If the below script is incorrect. Thanks

```
Option Compare Database

Public Function AuditChanges(RecordID As String, UserAction As String)
On Error GoTo auditerr

Dim DB As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim clt As Control
Dim UserLogin As String

Set DB = CurrentDb
Set rst = DB.OpenRecordset("select * from AuditTrail", dbOpenDynaset)

UserLogin = Environ("UserName")
Select Case UserAction
Case "new"
With rst
.AddNew
![DateTime] = Now()
!UserName = UserLogin
!FormName = Screen.ActiveForm.ActiveControl.Form.Name
!Action = UserAction
!RecordID = Screen.ActiveForm.ActiveControl.Form(RecordID).Value
.Update

End With


Case "Delete"
With rst
.AddNew
![DateTime] = Now()
!UserName = UserLogin
!FormName = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
!Action = UserAction
!RecordID = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(RecordID).Value
.Update
End With

Case "Edit"
For Each clt In InScreen.ActiveForm.ActiveControl.Form
If (clt.ControlType = acTextBox _
Or clt.ControlType = acComboBox) Then
If Nz(clt.Value) <> Nz(clt.OldValue) Then
With rst
.AddNew
![DateTime] = Now()
!UserName = UserLogin
!FormName = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
!Action = UserAction
!RecordID = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(RecordID).Value
!FieldName = clt.ControlSource
!OldValue = clt.OldValue
!newValue = clt.Value
.Update
End With
End If
End If
Next clt
End Select
rst.Close
DB.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set DB = Nothing

auditerr:
'MsgBox Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
Exit Function



End Function
```

There is no specific errors but the trail table is not getting picked up/updated.

Comment: if you use >=2010 you can take advantage of table triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that records are being succesfully added to your `AuditTrail` table, you should invoke the [`Requery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.requery) method of the form after modifying the data held in the underlying table.

Comment: Hi Lee, I also tried by updating the requery in VB script. but still the audit trail table doesnt get updated. Below is the query:

  
  Private Sub Form_Activate()
    Me.Requery
    Me.Repaint
    End Sub

Comment: Have you confirmed that records are being successfully added to the Audit Trail table?

Comment: It works now, i figuered it out. I was using this query in case edit "If (clt.ControlType = acTextBox _
Or clt.ControlType = acComboBox) Then" changed it to "if clt.ControlType = acComboBox". It works ver well. Thank you for the efforts.

Comment: You're welcome; please mark the question as resolved for the benefit of others viewing the site.

Comment: @KiranChapidi Condition is misspelled in `If (clt.ControlType = acTextBox _ Or clt.ControlType = acComboBox) Then` should be `If (clt.ControlType = acTextBox) _ Or (clt.ControlType = acComboBox) Then`

Comment: @4dmonster, But my query works fine no issues so far,.. I will also test your code. thank you so much